# GNU sed excludes unmatched lines

Tags: file-io, sed, gnu

I am using GNU sed command (GNU sed version 4.2.1) for search and replace in file.
I want the input file to remain intact hence I am using sed's file writing option.

Following is the command

```
sed -e "s/INSERT/UPDATE/w  output.txt" "input.txt"
```

But problem with above command is, it does not write the unmatched lines. i.e. the lines in which the text to be searched if not found then that line is not getting written in output.txt file.

I want unmatched lines to be written in output.txt

how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `w` as a separate command, i.e.:

```
sed -e 's/INSERT/UPDATE/' -e 'w output.txt' input.txt
```

or, if your `sed` supports it, you can use a semicolon:

```
sed -e 's/INSERT/UPDATE/;w output.txt' input.txt
```

But, if you really just want the output in a file, use redirection:

```
sed -e 's/INSERT/UPDATE/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks choroba, first option worked. I know third option but I can't use it as c# does not allow it to execute to provide the redirection option through ProcessInfo object.

Comment: Just to explain what's going on, the expression `s///w` means precisely "write if the substitution was successful", while `s///;w` are two commands substitute and (unconditionally) write.

Comment: I know nothing about `c#`, but surely the ProcessInfo object would allow you to write `sh -c "sed ... > output.txt"`.